# PHP data insertion not working using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to insert data into database using PDO.Connection established successfully,but **prepare** function isn't working.It's giving me an error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null
>   E:\xammp\htdocs\OOP\Project\classes\insert.php on line 8

My **index.php** page:

```
<?php

    function __autoload($cl){

        require_once "classes/$cl.php";

    }

    $connection = new database();

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
         $name = $_POST['name'];
         $email = $_POST['email'];
         $ph = $_POST['phone'];

        try
        {
            $ins = new insert();

        }
        catch(PDOEXCEPTION $e)
        {
            echo $this->con_error . $e->getmessage();
        }
    }
```

**classes/database.php:**

```
<?php

class database{

    public $db;
    public $con_error;

    protected function connection(){

        try
        {
            $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=oop","root","");
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $this->con_error="An error in connection" . $e->getmessage();
        }

    }
    public function __construct(){

        return $this->connection();

    }



}
```

**classes/insert.php:**

```
<?php

class insert extends database{
    public $stmt; 

    public function __construct(){

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`name`,`email`,`phone`) VALUES (:name,:email,:phone)");
        $stmt->bindParam(":name",$name);
        $stmt->bindParam(":email",$email);
        $stmt->bindParam(":phone",$ph);
        $stmt->execute();

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to call the parent class constructor from the child class's constructor. It doesn't happen automatically.

Comment: please use `spl_autoload_register()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insert` shouldn't be a child of `database`. If you do that for each operation, you'll end up with lots of classes that each have their own database connection. You should make them take the connection as a parameter, so they can all use the same connection.

Also, your function is using the variables `$name`, `$email`, and `$ph`, but they were not passed as arguments to the function. YOu shouldn't be performing the insert in the construtor, that should be done in a normal method. The constructor is just for initializing the class object.

```
class insert {
    private $db;

    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function insertUser($name, $email, $ph) {
        $stmt = $this->db->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`name`,`email`,`phone`) VALUES (:name,:email,:phone)");
        $stmt->bindParam(":name",$name);
        $stmt->bindParam(":email",$email);
        $stmt->bindParam(":phone",$ph);
        $stmt->execute();

    }

}
```

Then your main code would be like:

```
$database = new database;

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $ph = $_POST['phone'];

    try
    {
        $ins = new insert($database);
        $ins->insertUser($name, $email, $ph);

    }
    catch(PDOEXCEPTION $e)
    {
        echo $this->con_error . $e->getmessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: ! Why you put $db ???? I mean this is for what..And it's giving me an error

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: database in E:\xammp\htdocs\OOP\Project\index.php on line 67

Comment: @Barmar ! Kindly help me

Comment: I am unable to pass the variable which holds the connection object to the insert class as a Argument..

Comment: @Anonoymous I put a comment in your other question. I don't know why you're getting an error about `$database`, since it's clearly defined on the line before `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`.

Comment: Yeah. But  why u create a property $db?

Comment: @Barmar ! the error which i'm getting is :                                                 Fatal error: Call to undefined method db::prepare() in E:\xammp\htdocs\OOP\Project\classes_lib\insert.php on line 15

Comment: @Anonoymous The `insert` object needs to remember the `database` object that it was given when it was created. I changed the code to use `$this->db->db` so that it accesses the PDO object in the database object.