# How to pass a variable to a class in another page

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to insert data into my database.I have three pages.First is **index.php** where i've the form.Second is **db.php** which holds the connection to databse.Third one is **insert.php** which holds insertion code.The problem that i'm facing is that when i make the **insert** class ***child*** of ***database*** class,It works fine but when i use **insert** class a separate class from **database** class.It's giving me an error.In short,i am unable to pass a variable which contains the database connection **OBJECT** to the **insert** class.

**index.php**

```
<?php

function __autoload($cl){

    require_once "classes_lib/$cl.php";

}

$database = new db();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $ph = $_POST['phone'];

    try
    {
        $ins = new insert($database);
        echo $ins->insertUser($name, $email, $ph);

    }
    catch(PDOEXCEPTION $e)
    {
        echo $this->con_error . $e->getmessage();
    }
}
```

**classes_lib/db.php**

```
<?php

class db{

    public $con;
    public $con_error;

    public function connect(){

        try
        {
            $this->con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=oop","root","");
        }

        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $this->con_error = "An error in connecting to database" . $e->getmessage();
        }

    }

    public function __construct(){

        return $this->connect();

    }

}
```

**classes_lib/insert.php**

```
<?php

class insert{

    public $dbs;

    public function __construct($database){

        $this->dbs =  $database;
        return $this->dbs;

    }

    public function insertUser($name,$email,$ph){

        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`name`,`email`,`phone`) VALUES (:name,:email,:phone)");

        $stmt->bindParam(":name",$name);
        $stmt->bindParam(":email",$email);
        $stmt->bindParam(":phone",$ph);

        $stmt->execute();

    }

}
```

I'm so tired of the errors.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Comment: Didn't you post something very similar already and gotten an answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/39304513/ - your question here is a repost.

Comment: `$this->con` doesn't exist in `insert`

Comment: So what should i do

Comment: *"First is index.php where i've the form"* - There is no "form".

Comment: $fred! I didn't show the form because i've nothing wrong in my HTML

Comment: I'd suggest looking at some PHP tutorials, specifically ones talking about use of classes and objects. There a few basic errors in what you've provided.

Comment: @Anonoymous I can understand that you're having a similar problem here in regards to your question and you'd like to get it working. Wait for Barmar to get back to you (in your other question); he's usually pretty good at further helping. You just need to be patient. Your question here is really a repost and it could be closed as an exact duplicate.

Comment: `$this->con` should be `$this->dbs`. BTW, constructors shouldn't return anything. `new classname` always returns the object that's created, so the return value of the constructor is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

why dont you structure your code like this: 
in index.php: include/require the insert class then

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    //..call the insert class and pass the $_POST params in the insertUser    method 
    $class_insert = new insert();
    $class_insert->insertUser($_POST); // pass the values to the method
}
```

then in your class insert, require_once the db.php and then extend it:

```
class insert extends db
{
    // ..blah blah...

    public function insertUser($data){  // $data = $_POST param
        $database = new db();
        $db = $database->connect();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, email, phone) VALUES (:name, :email, :phone)";
        $q= $db->prepare($sql);

        $q->bindValue(':name',$data['name']);
        $q->bindValue(':email',$data['email']);
        $q->bindValue(':phone',$data['phone']);

        $q->execute();

    }
}
```